# Check if list sequence is in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a two different lists:

```
list_sequence = ['Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16']
```

and

```
list = ['Example 128', 'Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16', 'Example 256', 'Example 512', 'Example 1024']
```

I want to figure out, if the list_sequence is "in" the list.

Its important that the order of the list_sequence must be the same like in the list. (Maybe it would work with making the list an string?)

Comment: `print(list_sequence[1:-1] in list)`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016174/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-in-another-list-with-the-same-order-python)

Comment: A dup of a dup.

Comment: Wrote this. Not heavily tested. https://repl.it/repls/ExhaustedStingyServerapplication

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Your code returns false for the entire time.

Comment: New code: `print(list_sequence[1:-1] in str(list))`. And thanks

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 This is my debug:

['Spawn House Inside', 'Spawn House Ramp', 'Spawn House Roof', 'Spawn House Ramp', 'Spawn House Roof']
['Spawn House Roof', 'Spawn House Ramp', 'Spawn House Roof']
False

Your "fixed" version gives me: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: Newest code: `print(str(list_sequence)[1:-1] in str(list))`. Hopefully this works ;)

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 That worked, thanks! It doesnt matter when the sublist is in the list? At the very start, in the middle or at the very end? And one last request: Is it possible to return a count, of how many times the sublist has been in the list next to each other? Like a combo

Comment: `print(str(list_sequence)[1:-1].count(str(list)))`